# How we can do CRUD operations on complex data models in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datamodel, complextype, column-family, nosql

How we can do CRUD operations on complex data models in `Cassandra`?

- I have a project using NOSQL.
- I have a column family for my customers.
- The column family has just "id" at first.
- Then it will be updated by altering new columns.
- Count and type of columns for each customer could be different.
- Also, **each column can include sub columns with ids again and it would be altered, too. So, they should be indexed.** And documents are not useful for this issue.

I've read about NOSQL, and I've decided to use `Cassandra`. I will be thankful if you would answer this questions:

1. Is the above that possible?
2. How we can create and use `CRUD` operations on this column family?
3. If the answer of last question is true, **what is the type of result of a query?**
4. **It will return some rows for each primary key (id)?**
5. How we can manage that, to access a table like **with no redundancy**? because I don't now this summarizing should be manage in DBside or in code side.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This link helped me: http://www.slideshare.net/carlyeks/cassandra-materialized-views

Comment: It sounds like you chose Cassandra without really knowing what it is good for. It seems you want a Key Value Store. You can use Cassandra that way, but it's not the best fit.